# How to use hadoop pig streaming a compiled c program?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have testing the hadoop pig on a small cluster.

I have successfully using pig to stream perl, python, shell script and even jars but not c binaries!

I just build a simple Hello World program in c

And compiled it as test

And run it using ./test under ubuntu11.04 and g++ compiler is up to date.

The program run perfectly in the OS.

However when I tried to stream it in pig, it is always failed!

This is the pig script:

```
a = load ('test.txt');
define p `./test` ship('/home/clouduser/test');
b = stream a through p;
dump p;
```

test.txt contains only a space

and I have test the same configuration with perl, python, shell script and java successfully.

```
grunt> a = load 'test.txt';
grunt> define p `./1.sh` ship('/home/clouduser/1.sh');
grunt> b = stream a through p;
grunt> dump b
2011-09-08 23:53:33,940 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: STREAMING
2011-09-08 23:53:33,940 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - pig.usenewlogicalplan is set to true. New logical plan will be used.
2011-09-08 23:53:34,017 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - (Name: b: Store(hdfs://cloudlab-namenode/tmp/temp-502536453/tmp-1972014919:org.apache.pig.impl.io.InterStorage) - scope-2 Operator Key: scope-2)
2011-09-08 23:53:34,026 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2011-09-08 23:53:34,048 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2011-09-08 23:53:34,048 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2011-09-08 23:53:34,111 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2011-09-08 23:53:34,126 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2011-09-08 23:53:35,938 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2011-09-08 23:53:35,994 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2011-09-08 23:53:36,312 [Thread-9] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2011-09-08 23:53:36,313 [Thread-9] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2011-09-08 23:53:36,324 [Thread-9] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2011-09-08 23:53:36,324 [Thread-9] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library not loaded
2011-09-08 23:53:36,326 [Thread-9] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2011-09-08 23:53:36,494 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2011-09-08 23:53:37,101 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_201109051400_0283
2011-09-08 23:53:37,101 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - More information at: http://172.19.1.4:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201109051400_0283
2011-09-08 23:54:01,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201109051400_0283 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2011-09-08 23:54:01,762 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2011-09-08 23:54:01,774 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2055: Received Error while processing the map plan: './1.sh ' failed with exit status: 127
2011-09-08 23:54:01,774 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2011-09-08 23:54:01,776 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
0.20.2-cdh3u1   0.8.1-cdh3u1    clouduser       2011-09-08 23:53:34     2011-09-08 23:54:01     STREAMING

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201109051400_0283   a,b     STREAMING,MAP_ONLY      Message: Job failed! Error - NA hdfs://cloudlab-namenode/tmp/temp-502536453/tmp-1972014919,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://cloudlab-namenode/user/clouduser/test.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://cloudlab-namenode/tmp/temp-502536453/tmp-1972014919"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201109051400_0283


2011-09-08 23:54:01,776 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2011-09-08 23:54:01,793 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2055: Received Error while processing the map plan: './1.sh ' failed with exit status: 127
Details at logfile: /home/clouduser/pig_1315540364239.log
```

I even tried to run this file in shell script and ship the shell script and this c binary
but still failed!

Anyone has idea?!

StackOverflow Seems not allowing the original c code but the code runs fine

Answer (score 2):

From the given log:
Failed to read data from "hdfs://cloudlab-namenode/user/clouduser/test.txt"

Make sure you have the file test.txt in the cluster path "hdfs://cloudlab-namenode/user/clouduser/test.txt"

From the log line:
2011-09-08 23:54:01,793 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2055: Received Error while processing the map plan: './1.sh ' failed with exit status: 127

Check if ./1.sh can be executed?